# windows 7, some SWT dialogs are showed incomplete

Tags: java, windows-7, swt

I develop a RCP on windows XP, but when run on windows 7, some dialogs are showed incomplete. Usually, the widgets at the bottom of the dialog only show half, the other half were hidden because the dialog not big enough.

The problem happens on a win7, all the dialogs in my XP are displayed OK.

And I try to change resolution of XP and win7, At all resolution xp performs ok, but win7 failed.

I generated some dialogs of swt and jface, they are performs ok in XP, and incomplete in win7. \

Does anyone has some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can advise is to update your RCP to the newest version. SWT/JFace needed to be adapted to the specifics of Windows 7 UI, so if you are using an older version, it is bound to cause problems. To get any kind of advice more specific to your situation, it's not going to happen without a specific piece of your code that reproduces the phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks @MArko. I am using the 32 bit SWT jar since need to also get working in XP, what will be the best to use same jar.